# Positioning two elements side by side in the bottom?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position two buttons in the bottom side by side, they both must fill the width of the screen, so I make their width 50%
this is my HTML:

```css
#norm, #eco {
 background-color: #210511;
 color: white;
 width: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 z-index: 999;
}
#norm {
 float: left;
}
#eco {
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="btmBtnsContainers">
    <input type="button" name="normal" value="Normal" id="norm" />
    <input type="button" name="economy" value="Economy"  id="eco" />
</div>
```

but it ends with just one button, and the other is hidden!!

Comment: you should accept one correct answer dude :) thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your container `absolute` instead of the buttons. Like this:

```css
#btmBtnsContainers {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  z-index: 999;
}

#norm,
#eco {
  background-color: #210511;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="btmBtnsContainers">
  <input type="button" name="normal" value="Normal" id="norm" />
  <input type="button" name="economy" value="Economy" id="eco" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point of floating your buttons when you are absolute positioning them. Instead, assign left and right positions to them like this:

```css
#norm,#eco {
    background-color:#210511;
    color:white;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

#norm {
    left:0;
}

#eco {
    right:0;
}
```

```html
 <div id="btmBtnsContainers">
        <input type="button" name="normal" value="Normal" id="norm" />
        <input type="button" name="economy" value="Economy"  id="eco" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

NiZa's answer in one way of doing that, and here's another:

Since you've set `position:absolute` for inputs, they are placed in the same position. Just add `right:0` for one in order to place it on right side.

Also when you change `position` to `absolute`, the `float` property won't work anymore, so you can remove it.

```css
 #norm,#eco {
            background-color:#210511;
            color:white;
            width: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            z-index: 999;
        }
        #eco
        {
            right:0;
        }
```

```html
 <div id="btmBtnsContainers">
        <input type="button" name="normal" value="Normal" id="norm" />
        <input type="button" name="economy" value="Economy"  id="eco" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `left` and `right` instead of `float`.

```css
 #norm,#eco {
            background-color:#210511;
            color:white;
            width: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            z-index: 999;
        }
        #norm
        {
            left:0;
        }
        #eco
        {
            right:0;
        }
```

```html
 <div id="btmBtnsContainers">
        <input type="button" name="normal" value="Normal" id="norm" />
        <input type="button" name="economy" value="Economy"  id="eco" />
    </div>
```